# How is "the innermost child" framed in psychology?

Tags: terminology, inner-child

In art and literature, the adults are usually depicted as having a trapped child in their hearts:

[image]

The child is pure and naive, but is trapped in the adult body who is struggling to survive. I think this would simply be called as repression, and maybe in extreme case it can lead to [dissociative identity disorder](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/conditions/dissociative-identity-disorder-multiple-personality-disorder)? I think that in order to give a satisfactory answer, literature studies should also be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is mentioned in psychology to be the “[inner child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_child)”.

[Inner Child Therapy](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/evil-deeds/200806/essential-secrets-psychotherapy-the-inner-child/) is used within many different forms of therapy.  The inner child is often characterized as a subpersonality within the framework of [psychosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosynthesis) or may also be seen as a central element surrounded by subpersonalities. Virtually every talk therapy approach acknowledges and ascribes some meaning to the inner child, but in some cases they use a different label.  [Internal Family Systems Therapy (IFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Family_Systems_Model) has expanded the concept considerably in recognizing that there isn't just one inner child subpersonality, but many.

> Inner child therapy has been designed to help those who, as children, have been hurt by the adults and circumstances around them. They may have been hurt, not just by major, easily recognised traumas such as physical or sexual abuse or death of, or abandonment by, a parent, but also by the daily drip drip traumas such as neglect, rejection, criticism, humiliation, bullying, denial or confusion. ([Christopher, 2016](https://www.counselling-directory.org.uk/counsellor-articles/inner-child-therapy))

### References

Christopher, J. (2016). *Inner child therapy* [Online]
Retreived from: https://www.counselling-directory.org.uk/counsellor-articles/inner-child-therapy

Comment: Thanks for the many links. The IFS reminds me to the idea of animal zoo in [Why You Should Stop Caring What Other People Think (Taming the Mammoth) - Wait But Why](https://waitbutwhy.com/2014/06/taming-mammoth-let-peoples-opinions-run-life.html). Anyway, can that child "die" for being repressed so long? In general, how do we evaluate an approach?